# Searching for indexes of a two word string in a sentence with multiple instances of it(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some help with this program I am trying to write in python. When I search for "bachelors degree" in "degree : bachelors degree in bachelors degree" the output should be [2,3] and [5,6], but I'm getting only [2,3]

```
class FindString:

  def string1(self):
    self.main_string = "degree : bachelors degree in bachelors degree"
    self.sub_string = "bachelors degree"

  def count(self):
    sequence = self.main_string
    item = self.sub_string
    a = []
    temp = []
    for word_m in item.split():
        print(word_m)
        for index, word in enumerate(sequence.split()):
            if word.lower() == word_m.lower():
                if a == []:
                    a.append(index)
                    print("a1----------",a)
                elif index == a[-1] + 1:
                        a.append(index)
                        print("a2----------",a)
                else:
                    if a not in temp:
                        temp.append(a)
                        print("a3-------",a)



    print("a------------", a)
s = FindString()
s.string1()
s.count()
```

Comment: The indentation in your code does not make sense. Make sure you reproduce your indentation accurately when posting Python code. Otherwise you are introducing new errors into the code.

Comment: You should reverse the loops.

Comment: @khelwood Sorry i am new to this.

Comment: @akp can you elaborate please?

Comment: [2, 3] and [5, 6] are the expected results, but what are you getting currently?

Comment: Check the sub string in the main string by looping over main with inner loop checking for sub string. Here it seems you are doing opposite. Swap the loops and change code accordingly.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight [2,3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to achieve it

```
class FindString:

 def string1(self):
    self.main_string = "degree : bachelors degree in bachelors degree"
    self.sub_string = "bachelors degree"

 def count(self):
    sequence = self.main_string
    item = self.sub_string
    a = []
    temp = []
    for index, word in enumerate(sequence.split()):
        flag = 'no'
        for word_m in item.split():
            if word.lower() == word_m.lower():
                if a == []:
                    a.append(index)
                if a != []:
                    if index == a[-1] + 1:
                        a.append(index)
                    else:
                        flag ='yes'

        if flag == 'no':
            if a not in temp and len(a) == len(item.split()):
                temp.append(a)
            a = []
    print("temp---------", temp)

s = FindString()
s.string1()
s.count()
```